# How does Ruby JSON.parse differ to OJ.load in terms of allocating memory/Object IDs

Tags: json, ruby, memory-management

This is my first question and I have tried my best to find an answer - I have looked everywhere for an answer but haven't managed to find anything concrete to answer this in both the oj docs and ruby json docs and here.

Oj is a gem that serves to improve serialization/deserialization speeds and can be found at: https://github.com/ohler55/oj

I noticed this difference when I tried to dump and parse a hash with a NaN contained in it, twice, and compared the two, i.e.

```
# Create json Dump
dump = JSON.dump ({x: Float::NAN})
# Create first JSON load
json_load = JSON.parse(dump, allow_nan: true)
# Create second JSON load
json_load_2 = JSON.parse(dump, allow_nan: true)
# Create first OJ load
oj_load = Oj.load(dump, :mode => :compat)
# Create second OJload
oj_load_2 = Oj.load(dump, :mode => :compat)

json_load == json_load_2 # Returns true
oj_load == oj_load_2 # Returns false
```

I always thought NaN could not be compared to NaN so this confused me for a while until I realised that json_load and json_load_2 have the same object ID and oj_load and oj_load_2 do not.

Can anyone point me in the direction of where this memory allocation/object ID allocation occurs or how I can control that behaviour with OJ?

Thanks and sorry if this answer is floating somewhere on the internet where I could not find it.

Additional info:
I am running Ruby 1.9.3.

Here's the output from my tests re object IDs:

```
puts Float::NAN.object_id; puts JSON.parse(%q({"x":NaN}), allow_nan: true)["x"].object_id; puts JSON.parse(%q({"x":NaN}), allow_nan: true)["x"].object_id
70129392082680
70129387898880
70129387898880

puts Float::NAN.object_id; puts Oj.load(%q({"x":NaN}), allow_nan: true)["x"].object_id; puts Oj.load(%q({"x":NaN}), allow_nan: true)["x"].object_id    
70255410134280
70255410063100
70255410062620
```

Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't believe it's related to `object_id`s, I'm getting the same results with all **different** `object_id`s. UPD: ah, you meant the `NaN`'s `object_id`, I see. Could be a bug actually. With a significant runtime cost to fix... ._.

Comment: Hey @D-side, thanks for your reply.  That's odd. I've updated the OP to contain some extra info

Comment: I'm on a more recent one, somewhere between 2.2 and 2.3. I guess that's a quirk of `Hash#==`.

Comment: Wait @D-side - just to clarify - you made two hashes each time with both JSON and OJ and all of the created hashes had separate object IDs?

Comment: Yep, exactly. But then I checked `NaN`'s `object_id`s from inside these hashes and got results **same as yours**. I assumed you were talking about `NaN`s. If you **were not**, then...

Comment: Aha - then evidently it changed somewhere between Ruby 1.9.3. and 2.2 and this is possibly a bug with the Ruby JSON serializer.
My hashes have the **same** address when created by JSON and **different** results when created by OJ.

Comment: Considering JSON spec explicitly disallows `NaN`, blaming anyone for this may be tricky :)

Comment: I noticed it only when I tried to run specs and comparisons of these hashes that contained NaN values **passed** with JSON and **failed** with OJ.  I'll have to play around with 2.2 and see if it changes anything.  Unfortunately the project I'm working on will be stuck with Ruby 1.9.3. for a while yet.

Comment: Aha yes - perhaps the solution will be to workaround the matcher I'm using to handle the case whereby NaNs have been serialized/deserialized.  I'm happy with that answer, thank you @D-side ! :)  (food for thought - what happens with `Float::INFINITY` I wonder...)

Comment: So, to clarify: in the end I got two hashes from Ruby JSON serializer that had `NaN`s with the same `object_id`s. And I got two hashes from Oj that had `NaN`s of different `object_id`s. All four hashes had **distinct** `object_id`s. The former two compared equal, the latter two did not. I believe it's just the implementation: Ruby's JSON uses the same `Float::NAN`, while Oj just delivers floats that are decomposed by extension code one-by-one which may follow from its C code. I haven't dug that deep yet though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that is a **deep implementation detail**. [Oj does this](https://github.com/ohler55/oj/blob/eceb44ab26a3e30b8adcaba3817014e75a865edb/ext/oj/parse.c#L703):

```
if (ni->nan) {
  rnum = rb_float_new(0.0/0.0);
}
```

I can't find a Ruby equivalent for that, `Float.new` doesn't appear to exist, but it **does** create a new `Float` object every time (from an actual C's NaN it constructs on-site), hence different `object_id`s.

Whereas [Ruby's `JSON` module uses (also in C) its own `JSON::NaN` `Float` object everywhere](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/json/parser/parser.c#L2055):

```
CNaN = rb_const_get(mJSON, rb_intern("NaN"));
```

That explains why you get different `NaN`s' `object_id`s with Oj and same with Ruby's JSON.

---

No matter what `object_id`s the resulting hashes have, the problem is with `NaN`s. If they have the same `object_id`s, the enclosing hashes are considered equal. If not, they are not.

According to the docs, `Hash#==` uses `Object#==` for values that only outputs `true` if and only if the argument is **the same** object (same `object_id`). This contradicts NaN's property of not being equal to itself.

**Spectacular.** Inheritance gone haywire.

---

*One could, probably, modify Oj's C code (and even make a pull request with it) to use a constant like Ruby's JSON module does. It's a subtle change, but it's in the spirit of being `compat`, I guess.*